# Calculate the length of cord extended from spring loaded retractable drum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry

I am trying to calculate the length of flat cord extended from a drum.

Something similar to this would be a tape measure, but with cord that is flat and has a thickness of 0.1 inches. The cord thickness means that the diameter of the drum is constantly changing as you pull out the cord.

The equation I have come up with so far is [(Initial circumference+((Number of rotations-1)*change in circumference))= length of cord extended in rotation #]

I think there are some issues with this equation. I believe the correct model for this system involves differential equations but I am a little rusty. Any help is appreciated.[image]

Comment: How did you get your formula? What assumptions did you make?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the radius of the spool of cable decreases linearly with rotation angle as the drum is unwound. Then
$$\text{ total length of cable unwound} 
=\text{average of initial and final radii} \times \text{ angle turned through}$$

Note that this does not depend on the cable thickness. This is because a larger thickness results in a larger decrease in radius but a smaller unwind angle - the two effects cancel out.

*Derivation :*

Let the thickness of the cable be $w$ and the initial radius be $r_0$. The radius of the drum decreases by $w$ for every complete turn. Therefore after the drum has turned through angle $\theta$ the radius of the spool is $r=r_0-\frac{\theta}{2\pi}w$.

As the drum turns through small angle $d\theta$ the length of cable which is unwound is $ds=r(\theta)d\theta$. The total length unwound is :
$$s=\int_0^{\theta} r(\theta) d\theta = \int_0^\theta (r_0-\frac{w}{2\pi}\theta)d\theta=r_0\theta-\frac{w}{4\pi}\theta^2=\frac12 [r_0+(r_0-\frac{\theta}{2\pi})]\theta$$